# R. showing an error when xml again

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I am doing the android development with travis thenewboston on youtube. I'm getting an error in some lines with R. It was all working fine until i added my R.id.Exit and did a project clean then all went haywire. None of my xml files are throwing any warnings or errors. I have triple checked my spelling and i just think i need another set of eyes to help me out. Thank you in advance.

```
package com.apphouse.enterprises;

import android.R;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = { "StartingPoint", "TextPlay", "Email", "Camera",
        "Data", "Example5", "Example6", "Example7" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try {
        Class ourClass = Class
                .forName("com.apphouse.enterprises." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.apphouse.enterprises.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.Preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("com.apphouse.enterprises.PREFS");
        startActivivty(p);
        break;
    case R.id.Exit:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

private void startActivivty(Intent p) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

I have tried a project clean and also tried deleting the import android.R;  Not sure how that got there, but ya. Please any help would be awesome. My errors are being set on the ones with R.menu.cool_menu, and every R. below that.

This is xml, It is under my menu folder.

```
<item
    android:title="Preferences"
    android:id="@+id/Preferences"
    android:nuemericShortcut="1"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="a">

</item>
<item
    android:title="Exit"
    android:id="@+id/Exit">

</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu item I see you have an unknown xml attribute

```
android:nuemericShortcut="1"
```

I'm not sure if this it the only problem but change it to

```
android:numericShortcut="1"
```

and try to clean the project again.